# Parametric equation of rolling polygon (cyclogon)

Tags: parametric-functions, polygons

Abraham Gadalla  tried (but failed) to post the following question. Why does the red point not continue to follow the square (and the curve) for the full range $0\le x\le 2\pi$?

```
Manipulate[
  With[{q = Quotient[x, Pi/2], m = Mod[x, Pi/2]},
  Graphics[
  {EdgeForm[Black], LightGray, Rotate[{Rectangle[{q, 0}], 
  {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{q, q}]}}, -m, {q + 1, 0}],
  {Thick, Red, Circle[{1, 0}, 1, {Pi, Pi/2}], 
   Circle[{2, 0}, Sqrt[2], {3 Pi/4, Pi/4}],Circle[{3, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, 0}]}   
  }
  ]
], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

What simple modification is required to get this to work?

Answer (score 5):

`Point[{q,q}]` has to be changed:

```
Manipulate[
With[{q = Quotient[x, Pi/2], m = Mod[x, Pi/2]},
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightGray, 
Rotate[ {Rectangle[{q, 0}], {Red, PointSize[0.03],Point[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}}[[q + 1]]](* ,Point[{q,q}]*) } }, -m, {q + 1, 0}],
{Thick, Red,Circle[{1, 0}, 1, {Pi, Pi/2}], Circle[{2, 0}, Sqrt[2], {3 Pi/4, Pi/4}],Circle[{3, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, 0}]}},PlotRange -> {{-.10, 5}, {-.1 , 2}}]], {x, 0, 2 Pi .999}]
```

[image]

In the plot I added a last phase to show a complete rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Vielen Dank Herr Neumann  (Thank you Mr. Neumann )
I wonder, if it is possible to draw the path while the point is moving, Or writing a function of theta similar to the cycloid parametric equations:  x = r (theta - sin (theta)) and y = r (1 - cos (theta).
My main goal is to generalize the problem to write the parametric equations for the cyclogon.  The following part of a program shows the multiple of four polygons after moving them above the x-axis and to the right of the y-axis.  Please see below.
The next step is to find a function to draw a path while a point on its vertex is rotating.
I appreciate your help 
    Draw the Cyclogon

```
Manipulate[
 trM4 = Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], FaceForm[LightGray], 
     RegularPolygon[n]}, {PointSize[0.025], Blue, 
     Point[{Cos[\[Pi]/( n)] - Sin[\[Pi]/( n)], 0}]}, 
    If[hint, 
     Inset[Text@
       Style[TraditionalForm[{Cos[\[Pi]/( n)] - Sin[\[Pi]/( n)], 0}], 
        16, Black], {Cos[\[Pi]/( n)] - 
        Sin[\[Pi]/( n)], -0.2}]], {Translate[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], 
       FaceForm[{Yellow, Opacity[0.5]}], 
       RegularPolygon[n], {PointSize[0.03], Red, Point[{0, 0}]}}, { 
       Cos[\[Pi]/n], Cos[\[Pi]/n]}]}}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 400];
 Show[trM4],
 Row[{
   Control[{{n, 4, "Number of sides"}, 4, 21, 1, 
     Appearance -> "Labeled"}], Spacer[45], 
   Control[{{hint, False, "hint"}, {False, True}}]}], 
 TrackedSymbols :> {n, hint}]
```